# How to make an icon button open and close accordion slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have managed to create an accordion slider on my site but was looking to make some changes. Currently on my site:

http://s116169771.websitehome.co.uk/testsite/index2.html

I have 3 sections that scroll up or down by clicking the different rectangle boxes. What I would like to do is change the rectangle box with the current styles:

```
button.accordion {
    background-color: #eee;
    color: #444;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 18px;
    width: 960px;
    border: none;
    text-align: left;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 15px;
    transition: 0.4s;
}
```

by removing the padding:18px to 0px, then adding a height of 2px and lastly making the icon (arrow) the button to scroll up or down but I am not sure how i can change the code I have to achieve this or if it can actually be done.

By making the above changes, I can only open the sections if I click on the rectangle with the height of 2px and I would like to shift this to the button itself.

Would appreciate it, if somebody could advise if this is possible.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Make buttons child of the div(.panel), and try styling full width div and fixed width of button.

Comment: u used to image for button. image cut very poor. if u can - cut u image by rigth. or use css `transform-origin` for set point of `transform: rotate`.

Comment: thanks guys will try your suggestions and let you know how i get on